# Seeding session on server from a callback route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session, sapper

Trying to implement third party oauth authentication in Sapper.

As I understood following is the suggested pattern to seed and sync
session store on both server and client:

```
// In login.svelte
<script>
  import { stores } from '@sapper/app';
  const { session } = stores();

  async function login() {
    const res = await fetch('auth', {
      ...
    });

    if (res.ok) {
      session.update(store => ({
        ...store,
        user: await res.json()
      });
    } else {
      // handle the error
    }
  }
</script>

{#if $session.user}
  <h1>Welcome back {$session.user.name}!</h1>
{:else}
  <button on:click={login}>log in</button>
{/if}
```

```
// In auth.js
export function post(req, res) {
  req.session.token = req.body.token;
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ token: req.body.token }));
}
```

In my case, the auth system is implemented by a third party and instead
of an API, Its a website redirect. The User is redirected to Login/Register
page and on successful Login redirected to a 'callback' route.

In the callback route, I need to set the session and redirect but

1. If I set the req.session and res.redirect session is
   not getting set.

```
req.session.token = token;
res.redirect('/profile');
```

2. If I set req.session and then call next() session is set
   but cannot redirect to the intended 'profile' page.

```
req.session.token = 'parsed.token.wrwerwe9rwer';
return next();
```

Comment: Are you using the default polka server, or did you switch to express? IIRC, polka doesn't provide a `redirect` method on the response object, so you have to redirect explicitly, see https://github.com/lukeed/polka/issues/78.

Comment: Switched to express

Comment: This is really odd. I did something very similar to handle Spotify authentication in a sapper app and didn't have an issue setting the session, then redirecting. Spotify auth also uses a callback and a token system. I would gladly share my code if you're still having issues.

Comment: @ThomasHennes I will have to trouble you for the same.